# Passing a Python list to Post call return data Django

Tags: javascript, django

I have written a Post call in Javascript.

```
function chooseTeam(){
var myProject=document.getElementById("myProject").value
document.getElementById("myTeam").disabled=false;
$.post('http://localhost:8000/timer/populateteam/',{ "myProject": myProject},
        function(returnedData) {
            console.log(returnedData)
            console.log(typeof returnedData)


        });
}
```

In views i have written a view where i get a list

```
def populateteam(request):
    team_members_project=[]
    myTeam_project=request.POST.get("myProject")
    proj_obj = Project.project.all().filter(name=myTeam_project)
    team=Employee.employee.all().filter(projects=proj_obj)
    for i in range (len(team)):
        team_members=team[i].full_name()
        team_members_project.append(team_members)
```

How can i return the list to the javascript function. I am not using Django rest framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JsonResponse. Just pass the list to a jsonResponse and set the safe parameter to False

```
return JsonResponse(team_members_project,safe=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add these to your imports:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

Then inside your view, return a HttpResponse with the json encoded list like this:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(team_members_project), content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use HttpResponse and dump the list into the Json. Content type should be "application/json".

```
json.dumps(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode it using the functions in the json module.
`return json.dumps({'array':team_members})`

You can use `contentType: 'application/json'` in the header of your `POST` request to receive the JSON data.